# multiple google maps on one page with same style

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I want multiple google maps on one page.

I have this code but i don't know how can i do this.

What must be add?

I want other maps with the same styles.

one more problem is that google map don't load full

Can anyone help me?

```
    function initialize() {

            var styles = [
                {
                    featureType: 'water',
                    elementType: 'all',
                    stylers: [
                        { hue: '#E6E6E6' },
                        { saturation: -100 },
                        { lightness: 59 },
                        { visibility: 'on' }
                    ]
                },{
                    featureType: 'landscape.natural',
                    elementType: 'all',
                    stylers: [
                        { hue: '#999999' },
                        { saturation: -100 },
                        { lightness: -37 },
                        { visibility: 'on' }
                    ]
                },{
                    featureType: 'road',
                    elementType: 'all',
                    stylers: [
                        { hue: '#4C4C4C' },
                        { saturation: -100 },
                        { lightness: -53 },
                        { visibility: 'simplified' }
                    ]
                },{
                    featureType: 'landscape.man_made',
                    elementType: 'all',
                    stylers: [
                        { hue: '#ffffff' },
                        { saturation: -100 },
                        { lightness: 100 },
                        { visibility: 'on' }
                    ]
                },{
                    featureType: 'road.highway',
                    elementType: 'all',
                    stylers: [
                        { hue: '#bfbfbf' },
                        { saturation: -100 },
                        { lightness: 30 },
                        { visibility: 'on' }
                    ]
                },{
                    featureType: 'road.arterial',
                    elementType: 'labels',
                    stylers: [
                        { hue: '#bfbfbf' },
                        { saturation: -100 },
                        { lightness: -3 },
                        { visibility: 'simplified' }
                    ]
                },{
                    featureType: 'road.local',
                    elementType: 'geometry',
                    stylers: [
                        { hue: '#f1f1f1' },
                        { saturation: -100 },
                        { lightness: -5 },
                        { visibility: 'simplified' }
                    ]
                },{
                    featureType: 'poi',
                    elementType: 'all',
                    stylers: [
                        { hue: '#e6e6e6' },
                        { saturation: -100 },
                        { lightness: 55 },
                        { visibility: 'on' }
                    ]
                },{
                    featureType: 'poi.park',
                    elementType: 'all',
                    stylers: [
                        { hue: '#d0d0d0' },
                        { saturation: -100 },
                        { lightness: 16 },
                        { visibility: 'on' }
                    ]
                }
            ];

          var mapOptions = {
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
                mapTypeIds: [ 'Styled']
            },
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.96112215672197, 23.72348675727846),
            zoom: 16,
            mapTypeId: 'Styled'
          };

          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
              mapOptions);

          var styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles, { name: 'Styled' });

          map.mapTypes.set('Styled', styledMapType);
        }

        function loadScript() {
          var script = document.createElement('script');
          script.type = 'text/javascript';
          script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&' +
              'callback=initialize';
          document.body.appendChild(script);
        }

        window.onload = loadScript;
```

Comment: All your map instance have the same ID, therefore you cant only see one map (Styled). For each maps you want, give appropriate map options.

Comment: Cant you just add more canvas and call this multiple times with right id's? 
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('!!here your differenty id!!!'),
              mapOptions);

Comment: Bene can you give a sample of to maps with same style?

Comment: Yeronimo thank you very much, i solved this

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple google maps on one page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12284062/multiple-google-maps-on-one-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the following:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
var styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles, { name: 'Styled' });
map.mapTypes.set('Styled', styledMapType);
```

I'll explain one by one:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
```

This assignes to the variable `map` a new `google.maps.Map` type to the element ID `#map-canvas`

```
var styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles, { name: 'Styled' });
```

This assignes to the variable styledMapType a new `google.maps.StyledMapType`  with the style previously declared, and finally

```
map.mapTypes.set('Styled', styledMapType);
```

We call back again the `map` variable and use the `mapTypes.set` method to attach to it the `styledMapType` declared in the previous assignment.

If you want multiple maps in the same document you should in first instance create the new styling with var styledMapType, then create different maps on different containers and attach each style to each map you want styled.

At the end you should have something like this:

```
var styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles, { name: 'Styled' });

var map1 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map1'), mapOptions);
map1.mapTypes.set('Styled', styledMapType);
var map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map2'), mapOptions);
map2.mapTypes.set('Styled', styledMapType);
var map3 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map3'), mapOptions); 
// This map uses the standard styling
```

and on the HTML markup simply

```
<div id="map1"></div>
<div id="map2"></div>
<div id="map3"></div>
```

Ta-da, 3 maps running on the same page, with different styles.
Creating different settings variables using `mapOptions` as a template you can also apply different starting locations for each map, as using different `styledMapType` you can set different stylings:

```
var mapLondon = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapLondon'), mapLondonOptions);
mapLondon.mapTypes.set('Styled', styledMapLondon);
var mapNewyork = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapNewyork'), mapNewyorkOptions);
mapNewyork.mapTypes.set('Styled', styledMapNewyork);
```